# How to show api data with nodejs and the etherscan-api extension on http?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

At https://sebs.github.io/etherscan-api/
is an example how to get a balance.

```
var api = require('etherscan-api').init('YourApiKey');
var balance = api.account.balance('0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae');
balance.then(function(balanceData){
    console.log(balanceData);
});
```

This works fine.

**code:**

```
Server is created and listen on port 8080:

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
balance.then(function(balanceData){
    res.write(balanceData);
    res.end();
}).catch((error) => {
    assert.isNotOk(error,'Promise error');
    done();
});
```

**errors:**

> (node:2388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: assert is not defined
>
> (node:2388) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

What the code has to look like to show the result `balanceData` at `localhost:8080`?

Comment: Are you importing `assert` ?

Comment: Thanks for that quickly advice. No, I had not. Now I have initiated it with `var assert = require('assert');`. Now, I have got the following errors: (node:8976) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:8976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: assert.isNotOk is not a function

Comment: Makes sense. According to the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) that function does not exist.